# typeahead.js replace asp.net dropdownlist key/value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, typeahead.js

My goal is to replace an asp.net dropdownlist using typeahead.js.  I have an asp.net web service which returns a list of General Ledger Accounts encoded in json with an example below:

["10000 - Test Account","10001 - Test Account 2"]

Using a standard asp dropdown list I might assign the Name property to "10000 - Test Account" and the value property to 1 (whatever ID is in my database).  When I click the "add" button I would then use the value of the General Ledger item.  I can easily modify my webservice to return both a name and ID for each object however I don't know how to modify my typeahead code to store an id value from my database for each item and additionally how I can retrieve that value on selection of a GL.  My only solution at this point is to substring the first 5 chars of the name and do another database lookup but it just seems messy.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

**Snapshot from WebPage**
[image]

**Typeahead Code**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.typeahead').typeahead([
              {
                  name: 'theName',
                  remote: '/webservice.asmx/GetGLS?query=%QUERY',
                  limit: 10
              }
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply send back a JSON array with your value and data for each suggestion.

There is a custom event called typeahead:selected that you can hook. Here is an example with a local data source. Hopefully this will help you

http://jsfiddle.net/2yeW7/

HTML:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="test">
<input type="button" value="TEST" id="btn" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected = null;
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'countries',
        local: [{
            value: 'CASH-ATM',
            data: 10000
        }, {
            value: 'WAGES-1',
            data: 10001
        }, {
            value: 'WAGES-2',
            data: 10002
        }]
    });
    $('.typeahead').on("typeahead:selected", function (obj, datum) {
        selected = datum;
    });
    $('#btn').on("click", function() {
        alert("selected: " + selected.value + " datum - " + selected.data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly!  I had to modify my typeahead to use a template and the hogan engine but that's all.  Thanks!